# I can't convert a factor column to a numeric column in R

Tags: r, converters

I want to convert a factor column to a numeric one. I have tried the this code: `df$col_name= as.numeric(as.character(df$col_name))`.
But when I use this code it turns me a column with only NA value. I have also tried this code: `df$Col_name <- as.character(df$Col_name)` it gives a column with numbers like: `1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6` while I have a column with the following numbers: `10,3;11,4;12,4;18,4` etc.

Does anyone now which code I have to use?

Comment: Please show the dput of `df$col_name`

Comment: Is it `col_name` or `Col_name`?

Comment: I have changed the names to make it easy to understand. I don't use both of the names in real. This is the code I use : Geladen_Amsterdam$Gem_inkomen_Huishouden= as.numeric(as.character(Geladen_Amsterdam$Gem_inkomen_Huishouden))

Comment: We understand the codes you are using.  It should have worked for you.  If you can show a small reproducible example of your original data by updating the post, it would be better for us to give some suggestion.

Comment: Gem_inkomen_Huishouden=Factor w/ 60 levels "0,00","13,90",..:59 18 1 7 3 12 1 27 52 47... (This is before running the code)        And when I run the code I get the following df: Gem_inkomen_Huishouden= num NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA...

Comment: @user5543269 you can't use as.numeric directly on data like 0,00. Do you want to make two separate columns storing the numbers separately?

Comment: I want only the values > 0 but if I can't convert it  to numeric how can I filter it?

Comment: @user5543269 Do you want both the values to be > 0?

Comment: I want to make 2 new df's. One with the value in that column equal to 0 and one with >0.

Comment: @user5543269 As two numbers are written in that column, I am double checking the fact. Do you want both the values to be > 0 (or == 0) or it will be fine if any one of them is > 0 (or == 0)?

Comment: I want only the values that are greater then zero

Comment: the commas are probably coming from your data import step. If you are using `read.table` or `read.csv2` make sure you set `dec = ","`.

Comment: @user5543269 Please put the additional informations (given by you in the comments) in your question! Please edit yout question!

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the `,` by `.`:

```
df <- data.frame(Gem_inkomen_Huishouden=as.factor(c("0,00","13,90")))
df$Gem_inkomen_Huishouden <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", df$Gem_inkomen_Huishouden, fixed=T))
df$Gem_inkomen_Huishouden
# [1]  0.0 13.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way:

```
col_char=as.character(Geladen_Amsterdam$Gem_inkomen_Huishouden))

str_split <- strsplit(col_char,",")

indices <- which(sapply(1:nrow(Geladen_Amsterdam),function(x){
    num <- as.numeric(str_split[[x]])

    if (sum(num>0) == 2)
        return (T)
    else
        return (F)
}))
```

This will give you the indices which can be used for further filtering.

Note that it returns indices of only those columns which have values > 0. That is, if say, '10,2' is the value, it will return its index, otherwise if it is like "7,0", '0,7', '0,0' etc, it won't return its index.

Answer (score 0):

Comma is the problem. Use gsub to change comma to dot and then you can convert to numeric

```
 a <- as.factor(c("10,3", "11,4", "12,4"," 18,4"))
 a <- gsub("," , ".", a)
 a <- as.numeric(as.character(a))
```